# Find and Replace string in all files recursive issue

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I try this command to find and replace string in my android project.

```
find . -name '*.java' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" "s;//\#Logger\.;Logger\.;g"
```

//#Logger.  =>   Logger.

It's work but in some files i have unexpected changes. With git diff i get:

```
-}
\ No newline at end of file
+}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I think it should be xargs -0 sed -i  {} "s...."

Comment: I.e. probably you forgot {}

Comment: sed: {}: No such file or directory

Comment: right, see the answer. Found OPs problem as well

Comment: phnmnn, the question says that, aside from the newline issue, the command worked for you.  But, I just tried your command on Android and, like @RobertNavado observed, the android `sed` did not accept the BSD-style `-i ""` option (with the space between `-i` and `""`).  Is that actually the command that you used and that worked?

Comment: yes. the command is work. but i have issue with unexpected changes

Answer (score 1):

Well, just figured out the problem.
Your code should work as following (remove redundand "" after -i in sed):

```
find . -name '*.java' -print0|xargs -0 sed -i "s;//\#Logger\.;Logger\.;g"
```

Alternatively you can use parallel instead xargs and run this even faster:

```
find . -name '*.java' -print0|parallel -0 sed -i "s;//\#Logger\.;Logger\.;g" {}
```

And suggested below find .. -exec variant:

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec sed -i "s;//\#Logger\.;Logger\.;g" {} +;
```

Comment: You right, find -exec is a good one.
Figured out his error, changing the answer..

Comment: Plus 1 for spotting the `-i ""` issue.

Comment: i try first option, error: sed: 1: "./android_project/build/ ...": invalid command code .

Comment: It seems that it's version specific. Can you try -exec variant?

Comment: Are you on bash and Linux?

Comment: MacOS bash terminal

Comment: with"" it's work but i have the issue with "-}\ No newline at end of file+}"

Comment: With every syntax?

Comment: same result with every syntax